# Javascript Event Delegation issue with target

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML (example):

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <img src="...">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <img src="...">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <img src="...">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have like, 1000 of the `div.b`. I need to add event listener to `div.a` and target the `div.b` children.

However the `event.target` may also be `img`, or `p`:

```
document.querySelector('.a').addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e){
   console.log(e.target); //either .b or img or p depending on where I click
}
```

I need something like this (jQuery):

```
$('.a').on('click', '.b', function(){
   //code
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest Though not widely supported yet, there's also a polyfill on the MDN page.

Comment: If that is your actual structure, test if event.target is a div.p and if not then use event.target.parentElement

Comment: Yeah I know but I'm looking for a more flexible solution, the best practice

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your query selector like in css file, to select the children of class.

The following code tested on clicking the search bar on SO. you can try it on console

```
document.querySelector('.top-bar .f-input').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: yes but that's only if you have one element, if you have multiple (like in my case, I have thousands) you need to add an event listener for every node and performance will be bad